# How to render single react component with different data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created `Barchart` component (displays barchart) which is child component. In parent component I am passing `props` to `Barchart` component. In `Barchart` component I am using `if/else` and to render the `Barchart` accordingly.

Barchart component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Barchart extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }

  componentDidMount(){

    if(this.props.statType === 'batting'){

        const data1 = {
            labels: ['XS', 'S', 'M', 'L', 'XL', 'XXL', 'XXXL'],
        series: [20, 60, 120, 200, 180, 20, 10]
        }

        const options1 = {
            width:300,
            height:300,
            distributeSeries: true
        }

        const mychart1 = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-bar-chart', data1,options1);

    }else if(this.props.statType === 'bowling'){

      const data1 = {
        labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
        series: [200, 600, 120, 200, 1800, 200, 100]
      }

      const options1 = {
        width:300,
        height:300,
        distributeSeries: true
      }

      const mychart1 = new Chartist.Bar('.ct-bar-chart', data1,options1);
    }
}
  render(){
    return(
         <div className="ct-bar-chart">
             {this.mychart1}
         </div>
    )}
}

export default Barchart;
```

Bowling component:

```
return(
      <div><Barchart bowldata={this.props} statType='bowling'/></div>
)
```

Batting component:

```
return(
      <div><Barchart batdata={this.props} statType='batting'/></div>
)
```

I am able to see barchart on batting page (i.e batting component) but on bowling page (i.e bowling component) nothing is displayed.

Comment: put everything in the render method

Comment: @niklas `render()` method is very large so I cannot put entire code. If possible can you share some working example on jsfiddle or sandbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `ref` in while initializing graph rather than class. Consider below code:

```
render(){
    return(
         <div className="ct-bar-chart"
              ref={(ele) => this.chartElement = ele}>
              ...
         </div>
    )}
```

Now while initializing chart use:

```
const mychart1 = new Chartist.Bar(this.chartElement, data1,options1);
```

So the advantage here here is `this.chartElement` is unique for every component, while if you use class it can conflict with another component.

Comment: @Hirday Woow it works now. I am newbie and just started learning reactjs. I want to know why does adding `ref` works ? I had mostly used `props` earlier and never tried to used `ref`.

Comment: Could you please add more explanation in your answer because as I couldn't understand why does it work ?

Comment: As of I know both ref and pros are unique for every component. props are the good solution instead of ref

Comment: @KevalBhatt I have used props but when I change it to ref it works fine. With props it does not work

Comment: @stonerock because ref has the `element` which is very specific to each component you are initializing while `class` on which you are initializing chart may conflict with `class` used in another component. Hence `ref` works better. I will add it in my answer too.

Comment: @HridayModi So you mean props is not specific to each component but ref's are specific to each component is that right ?

Comment: No both are specific to component. So here you are passing different data to 2 component instances but the `css class` on which chart is initialized is same for both of them hence we used ref.

Comment: @HridayModi Ok so can you tell me the use case of refs because refs are not used much compared to props. When should I use refs for my components ?

Comment: @HridayModi Why did you used `refs` with a callback can't we use `ref={chartElement}`

Comment: @stonerock Have a look at [When to use refs?](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs). Also you can use the latest way of creating ref as mentioned [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#adding-a-ref-to-a-dom-element). I have used functional ref as i am used to it.

Comment: @HridayModi I still could not understand why in my case you have used `ref` because I have seen in the docs refs are used when managing focus, animation but none of them I am doing in my case.

Comment: There is third point too there __Integrating with third-party DOM libraries.__ Which is your use-case.